# How do I use the sum() function in Python to find the sum of all positive numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list, testing, calculation

**Edit 1:** Solved! The solution was using `i for i in arr if i > 0`, which was given to me by @sushanth.

Final product of the code:

```
def positive_sum(arr):
    return sum(i for i in arr if i > 0)
```

---

I am trying to complete some Codewars challenges, and I came across one that is giving me issues. I am given a list of positive and negative numbers, and I am supposed to find the sum of all of the positive numbers.

Here is what I already have:

```
def positive_sum(arr):
    for n in arr:
        if n < 0:
            arr.remove(n)
    return sum(arr)
```

Here are the lists I am supposed to be working on:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[1,-2,3,4,5]
[-1,2,3,4,-5]
[]      
[-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]
```

However, whenever I run the tests, all of the tests pass except for the last one, with all of the negative numbers. For some reason, the result of it is `-6`, even though all negative numbers should have been removed.

Why is this? What should I do to make sure all of the tests pass?

Comment: instead of remove, you can use ``sum(i for i in arr if i > 0)`` ?

Comment: Don't remove from a list while iterating it. You're messing with the iterator which can lead to elements being skipped.

Comment: @sushanth yep, that worked! I did something similar to this from another stackoverflow post, but I think it was meant to be used in another use case. This one worked perfectly!

Comment: @Carcigenicate oh, alright. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 2):

try **sum()** with generator and **if** condition:

```
result = sum(x for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] if x > 0)
print(result)
```

Comment: No need to use a `list` comprehension, `sum()` can take a generator as an argument. Creating a `list` first wastes memory and computation time.

Comment: Although, play around with it. Generator expressions also tend to be slower, so for small lists, a comprehension may be the better option if the extra memory usage is acceptable.

Comment: entirely agreed, changed to generator, good catch, thanks!